# Matrix iteration doesn't return

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to make a function with R, which finds ones from the matrix(user gives this 10x10matrix). Then this function is going to save those ones' places to the other matrix "mat" which is 100x2matrix. In this "mat", the first column is the place's row number and the second column is the place's column number. The problem is that my function saves to the "mat" only the first one's place. For example: this is a sample matrix i made for testing:

```
   Browse[1]> D
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
 [2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

and now my function only saves  (1,7) to the first row of "mat", when every else row is (0,0). Thanks for helping.

```
 f <- function(A) {
 B <- matrix(A, nrow =10, ncol =10 )
 mat <- matrix(0, nrow=100, ncol=2)
 
 for (i in 1:10) {
     for (a in 1:10) {
            
         if (B[i,a]==1) {
             for(b in 1:100) {
                 mat[b,]<-c(i,a)
                 return(mat) }
         }
     }
  }
 }




   Browse[1]> f(D)
       [,1] [,2]
  [1,]    1    7
  [2,]    0    0
  [3,]    0    0
  [4,]    0    0
  [5,]    0    0
  [6,]    0    0
  [7,]    0    0
  [8,]    0    0
  [9,]    0    0
 [10,]    0    0
 ...
```

If I change the return(mat) location:

```
f<- function(A) {
B <- matrix(A, nrow =10, ncol =10 )
mat <- matrix(0, nrow=100, ncol=2)


for (i in 1:10) {
    for (a in 1:10) {
        
        if (B[i,a]==1) {
            for(b in 1:100) {
                mat[b,]<-c(i,a)
                }
        }
    }
}
return(mat)
}  


Browse[1]> f(D)
   [,1] [,2]
  [1,]   10   10
  [2,]   10   10
  [3,]   10   10
  [4,]   10   10
  [5,]   10   10
  [6,]   10   10
  [7,]   10   10
  [8,]   10   10
  [9,]   10   10
 [10,]   10   10
 ...
```

Comment: Of course if you have `return` in a loop then the function returns in the first iteration of the loop. Why not have a `return` outside of the loops? It isn't clear what the function is supposed to do. Please elaborate.

Comment: Well, if i move return after the for loops, it is going to return hundred rows of c(10,10). I think that happends because  D[10,10] = 1. So the place (10,10) is right here, now it is the last possible place, but again it doesn't return the other places. And this time it just multiplies that last one.     The function is supposed to return that 100x2 matrix, where is all the ones' places from the first matrix, which user gives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't want to spoil your fun :-) but

```r
which(A==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

will I think do what you're trying to do ... (the results won't be quite identical as `which()` will return only as many as rows as there values equal to 1 in the matrix, while yours always returns 100 rows)

---

If you do want to write this yourself (very inefficiently!) you need to use a counter that keeps track of the current row:

```r
f <- function(A)  {
   B <- matrix(A, nrow =10, ncol =10 )
   mat <- matrix(0, nrow=100, ncol=2)
   k <- 1
   for (i in 1:10) {
     for (j in 1:10) {  
        if (B[i,j]==1) {
            mat[k,] <- c(i,j)
            k <- k+1
        }
      }
   }
   return(mat)
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I should laugh or cry(I already cried), but this was exactly what I meant and this solved my problem. And this was the perfect answer too( I thought that I could delete all the (0,0) rows after making this function work, but it is perfect now). Altough it would have been nice to know what was the problem in my function XD . Thank you so much :-)